# How To Translate SQL Inner Join, Groupby Into Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Here I have SQL query, now I am trying to translate it into linq but don't have any idea how to do it and got stuck in getting `ChapterId` from `ChapterQuestion` table.
Any help with translation will be grate.
Thank you

Below is my sql query

```
SELECT  CQ.ChapterId,CQS.SetNumber,count(distinct CQ.ChapterQuestionId) as questioncount FROM 
[dbo].[ChapterQuestion] AS CQ 
JOIN [dbo].[ChapterQuestionSet] AS CQS ON CQ.ChapterQuestionSetId = CQS.ChapterQuestionSetId
WHERE CQ.ChapterId = 1 group by CQS.SetNumber,CQ.ChapterId
```

Below is my linq

```
 var list = (from CQS in uow.Repository<ChapterQuestionSet>().GetAll().ToList()
                    join CQ in uow.Repository<ChapterQuestion>().FindBy(x => x.ChapterId == chapterId).ToList()
                    on CQS.ChapterQuestionSetId equals CQ.ChapterQuestionSetId
                    group CQ by CQS into G1
                   
                    select new ChapterQuestionSetVM
                    {
                        ChapterQuestionSetId = G1.Key.ChapterQuestionSetId,
                        Count = G1.Count(t => t.ChapterQuestionSetId != null),
                        QuestionSetNo = $"Question set {G1.Key.SetNumber}",
                       ChapterId = // how do i get chapterid from ChapterQuestion
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is all black-box code. It doesn't give any idea how it could translate into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is corrected query. I hope `Repository.GetAll()` returns `IQueryable`?
This query works only with EF Core 5.x

```cs
var query = 
    from CQS in uow.Repository<ChapterQuestionSet>().GetAll()
    join CQ in uow.Repository<ChapterQuestion>().GetAll() on CQS.ChapterQuestionSetId equals CQ.ChapterQuestionSetId
    where CQ.ChapterId == 1
    group CQ by new { CQS.SetNumber, CQ.ChapterId } into G1
    select new ChapterQuestionSetVM
    {
        ChapterId = G1.Key.ChapterId
        QuestionSetNo = $"Question set {G1.Key.SetNumber}",
        Count = G1.Select(t => t.ChapterQuestionSetId).Distinct().Count(),
    };
 
 var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Would have been a good spot to put a Linq2DB solution side-by-side :P